# How to visit Colorado mountains during the winter without driving through unsafe road conditions to get to the transit service?

Tags: public-transport, transportation, winter, snow, colorado

I will be taking a winter road trip and as part of that road trip, I'd like to see the mountains of Colorado. I've seen them in the fall, but would love to experience them in Winter.  The car I will be driving is 2 wheel drive. Also I have no experience in icy or snowy roads.

There are transit options from Colorado cities into the mountains, such as Colorado Springs into ski resorts. My problem is I suspect places like Colorado Springs itself will be difficult to drive into because of unsafe road conditions. Are there transit options from less snowy places that are less likely to have snow? Perhaps southern Colorado or New Mexico? I will be coming from Florida.

How to visit Colorado mountains during the winter without driving through unsafe road conditions to get to the transit service?

Comment: We don't leave snow on the roads all winter. We remove it right after each snowstorm. You can just drive directly to wherever you want to go, provided you aren't driving _in_ or _immediately after_ a snowstorm.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I was told by a friend who lived in Colorado that I should avoid any driving in Colorado, especially cause I have no experience with icy roads and have a 2 wheel drive car. Will I be able to kill time in beautiful New Mexico and wait for a favorable stretch of weather and drive myself into the state?

Comment: Sure, but it snows in New Mexico too. Perhaps you shouldn't drive on icy roads, but where are you going to find those?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm a bit confused now. Would you recommend I simply drive in during clear weather, or simply avoid this sort of road trip during winter altogether?

Comment: As I said before, I think you're far more worried about it than you should be. There isn't any snow or ice on any road you're likely to want to travel. There isn't even any weather in the 10-day forecast. Just don't drive in a snowstorm and you'll be fine.

Comment: @MichaelHampton That's good to hear. I've heard different things from different people. Our itinerary is completely flexible so we shouldn't have trouble working around the weather.

Comment: cotrip.org is Colorado's DOT website. It has information on [current road conditions](http://www.cotrip.org/map.htm#/roadConditions) to get an idea of how bad the conditions are and even [images from the highway cameras](http://www.cotrip.org/map.htm#/default?StillCameraId=10082).

Comment: @clcto that is amazing and is exactly what I was looking for to get an idea of what typical winter traffic conditions actually look like in Colorado. Thanks!

Comment: @Goose take a look again tomorrow morning especially up in Fort Collins and you will get an idea of how they can be during a storm - not that tomorrow storm is going to be particularly bad. And in the following days to get an idea how quickly it gets cleared.

Comment: We have a train from Denver to winter park on weekends, if that fits your schedule. Google "Denver ski train" and it'll tell you how to get tickets and such.

Comment: Colorado Springs is the second-largest city in Colorado and it's at the intersection of an Interstate and a US highway. You should surely be able to get to Colorado Springs by car. Also, unless everybody in Colorado owns a 4x4 for use in the winter, a 2wd car is surely adequate on major roads and roads within cities, with appropriate caution.

Comment: Is there some reason that just getting on a plane from Florida to Denver isn’t an option here?

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz because I am doing this as one stop of several on a road trip. I'll also be visiting New Orleans, Texas, New Mexico, and all the open highways in between. I could take a plane from New Mexico to Colorado, but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to visit Colorado mountains during the winter without driving
>   through unsafe road conditions to get to the transit service?

If you are uncomfortable driving in (potentially) snowy and icy conditions, then the easiest thing is to not do it.  And by this I don't mean not to visit, I mean that you could organize your trip so that someone else does the driving for you.

> My problem is I suspect places like Colorado Springs itself will be
>   difficult to drive into because of unsafe road conditions.

This could be solved by stopping driving at some distant location and then taking Amtrak or Greyhound to the city center and then picking up transfers into the mountains.  The big caveat here is that a major snow storm could hit the plains areas juts as you arrive at your stop off point, and hence negate all your careful planning

Back a long time ago I arrived by Amtrak in Denver and then took a shuttle bus up to Breckinridge. (I picked the train up in Chicago - so came no where near to driving in the mountains)

---

And in my experience, even people who grew up driving in areas with snow still have issues getting around. So I commend you for recognizing your limitations.

And as an unrelated anecdote, the Amtrak train from Denver to San Fran goes over though some spectacular mountain scenery in the Rockies.  I think it's a great trip to take.

Answer (score 4):

Amtrak's [California Zephyr](https://www.amtrak.com/california-zephyr-train) will take you through the Rockies along the Colorado River. The train is equipped with observation, dining and sleeping cars, and the scenery is spectacular - I would absolutely recommend as a trip it by itself.

In terms of providing access to the mountains, you can pick it up anywhere from Chicago to San Francisco, or, closer by, in Denver. It won't take you to Colorado Springs, but it does stop in the mountains - notably at [Winter Park](https://www.winterparkresort.com/) (which is also served by Amtrak's [Winter Park Express](https://www.amtrak.com/winter-park-express) from Denver) - and onwards to stations such as [Hot Sulphur Springs](http://hotsulphursprings.com/).

It won't avoid the roads, but Colorado Springs is served by [Amtrak Thruway Motorcoaches](https://www.amtrak.com/stations/cos); these stop at [the Greyhound station](http://locations.greyhound.com/bus-stations/us/colorado/colorado-springs/bus-station-830104), so there'll be Greyhound services there too.

Comment: I've taken that Amtrak trip, and it is spectacular.